# Scroll-down all the way without error "beginning of buffer"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please, to programmatically scroll a particular window to the very beginning without incurring an `error` *beginning of buffer* (which necessarily halts the function).  The current `(point)` is within the visible window, but near the bottom.  The number of lines to `scroll-down` may vary, so I cannot say for sure exactly how many is needed -- but the very beginning of the buffer is what I'm looking for.  I don't think `(save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)))` will do what I want.

`scroll-down` does not have an argument for a specific window, so if the solution to this question could also include an example to perform the action with a specific window (without switching to it), that would be greatly appreciated.  In other words, I'd like to be in a different window while this function is going on in the target window.

```
(when
    (not (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-min)
       (get-buffer-window calendar-buffer (selected-frame))))
  (scroll-down 20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `scroll-down` in a `condition-case` to regain control when an error is signaled:

```
(condition-case nil
    (scroll-down 20)
  (error nil))
```

I wasn't exactly sure if you wanted your last code snippet was part of the function you were referring to, but you can wrap it all in a `save-selected-window`:

```
(let ((cal (get-buffer-window calendar-buffer (selected-frame))))
  (when cal
    (save-selected-window
      (select-window cal)
      (condition-case nil
          (scroll-down 20)
        (error nil)))))
```

EDIT: jpkotta suggested `ignore-errors` in the comment, which I agree looks cleaner:

```
(ignore-errors
  (scroll-down 20))
```

Comment: There's also the slightly nicer looking `ignore-errors`.  It's equivalent to your `condition-case`.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(let ((win (get-buffer-window calendar-buffer (selected-frame))))
  (when (not (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-min) win))
    (set-window-start win (point-min))))
```

---

```
`set-window-start` is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(set-window-start WINDOW POS &optional NOFORCE)

Make display in WINDOW start at position POS in WINDOW's buffer.
WINDOW must be a live window and defaults to the selected one.  Return
POS.  Optional third arg NOFORCE non-nil inhibits next redisplay from
overriding motion of point in order to display at this exact start.
```

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Start-and-End.html

---

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Selecting-Windows.html